# How to parse string with key value pair inside in redshift

Tags: sql, parsing, amazon-redshift, extract, key-pair

I have a text column in Redshift and want to extract manager or manager employee id from:

```
"Manager"=>"Alex Dar"
, "Cost Center"=>"02-40-731"
, "Manager employee ID"=>"testing@test.com"
, "Manager First Name"=>"Sohn",
```

I'm expecting to get manager, manager employee id and Manager First Name

Answer (score 0):

So, here is solution.
At first, change it to json and then parse the json.
json_extract_path_text(concat('{',concat(replace(custom_fields,'=>',':'),'}')),'Manager employee ID')

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).